# Remove the %s in the textarea tag python

Tags: python

```
form="""
<textarea>%s</textarea>
"""
```

I am trying to make a post request using the textarea input, and show the post input in the textarea again and I am able to do that.

But, my problem is in the beginning when I first go to see the page, I see the **%s** in the textarea box. How do I hide the **%s**? I am using the old python, I think it is 2.7

```
form="""
    <form method="post">
      <textarea name="text">%s</textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
"""        
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.write(form)
  def post(self):
      foo="posted to the box"
      self.response.write(form %foo)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: I think the batter way is to write something like this: 

`form="""
<form method="post">
<textarea name="text">%s</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form % ('', ))

    def post(self):
        foo="posted to the box"
        self.response.write(form % (foo, ))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
print form.replace('%s', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Put something in its place.

```
print form % ('',)
```

Comment: He probably literally wrote that.  
@JohnHenderson you should do `form = form % ''`. I think `form = form.replace('%s', '')` is clearer though.

Answer (score 0):

Easier, just put %s as value parameter:

```
<textarea name="text" value="%s"></texarea>
```

this will create a nice blank textarea ;)